# How to align the product page in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a website with WordPress and wanted to center the elments on this page: https://www.web-demo-site.eu/trgovina/trepalnice-004-c/

I've tried things like:

- margin: auto !important;
- all kinds of alignments:center !important;

But nothing seems to work.
Currently I have:

```
#content div.product.type-product{
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Which works, but not correctly since it's not aligned well on all devices.
Is there a way to align the content on the Product Page from Woocommerce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to archive this is:

1. Removing the `margin-left` from `#content div.product.type-product`.
2. Adding `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to
   `.single-product .woocommerce-container`.

Another way is removing the `float`, and adding a `margin: 0 auto` to `.single-product .woocommerce-container #content`

---

**Solution 1**:

```
.single-product .woocommerce-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**Solution 2**:

```
.single-product .woocommerce-container #content {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can add the CSS to the Customizer, or your child theme's CSS.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly. I just found another "solution" which would take a while to aplly on all products... that was to change Fusion builders "Use 100% Width Page" option to "No"... Thanks, you're a savior ^^

Comment: Would the same thing be possible for the category page ?
https://www.web-demo-site.eu/kategorije/trepalnice/

Comment: I tried both methods, but to replace the ".single-product" with "product-category"... didn't seem to work

Comment: @McBooley, the selector you have to use on that page is `.tax-product_cat .woocommerce-container`